# Label Expression Help - Null Value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, data-driven-pages

```
"Rec" & " " & [RECEPTION] & VbNewLine & "Bk" &[BOOK] & " " & "Pg" &[PAGE]
```

This is what I have so far. I want to make it so that if the Rec number is blank OR null to label Book and Page. Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: You have already asked this question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190061/label-expression) and it was already marked as duplicate.  If you don't think it's a duplicate then please edit that question with more information.  As far as I can tell the marked [answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73015/64785) to the question will work.  Please edit your original question to include details about why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just make separate label classes and query what you want for each class. Your first class would be for Rec IS NOT NULL and then the second class would be for Rec IS NULL. Edit your expression accordingly.